# How to store an arraylist into a string and send it to a server as a request in Android?

Tags: java, android, string

How can I send a string to a server as a request? After getting response, I should again split the string in to parts. I have stored an `ArrayList` into string here:

```
ArrayList<String> contactlist=new ArrayList<String>();
        contactlist.add("Android");
        contactlist.add("tarnaka");
        contactlist.add("uppal");
        contactlist.add("Prasad");

        String[] contact=new String[contactlist.size()];
        contact=contactlist.toArray(contact);
```

Comment: Use `JSON` format to send data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here u are...

```
ArrayList<String> contactlist = new ArrayList<String>();
    contactlist.add("Android");
    contactlist.add("tarnaka");
    contactlist.add("uppal");
    contactlist.add("Prasad");

    StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer("");

    for (String temp : contactlist) {
        sb.append("-" + temp);
    }

    String stringToSend = sb.toString();

    MyLog.printLog("String : " + stringToSend);

    String[] rString = stringToSend.split("-");

    for (String s : rString) {
            MyLog.printLog("Names : " + s);
    }
```

Comment: To help others, please upvote my answer if you thinks it deserves.

Answer (score 0):

To join `ArrayList` into a string Use

```
String joined = TextUtils.join(",", contactslist.toArray());
```

See: [http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/TextUtils.html#join(java.lang.CharSequence, java.lang.Object[])](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/TextUtils.html#join%28java.lang.CharSequence,%20java.lang.Object%5B%5D%29)

Answer (score 0):

Make a string by inserting "-" in between of ArrayList objects. Sent that string. For getting the array of names call `string.split("-")`enter code here`at other end. You r done.

Comment: Could you provide any similar examples? @Jatin